# I am calling a third party API and it is giving null in the response

Tags: c#, base-url

Hello everyone I had a problem while calling a Kiwi API in my API but I am facing a problem in URL part because my URL is not forming according to URL formed by The KIWI APP let me show you my code in which I am passing my parameters

```
public ApiResult<KiwiFlightDetails> GetKiwiFlightDetails()
{

    string endPoint = "/search";

    var flightResult = _httpService.Get<KiwiFlightDetails>(
    endPoint: endPoint,
    headers: new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"apikey",_serviCeconfig.Kiwi_Key}
    },
    parameters: new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "fly_from", "FRA"},
        { "fly_to", "PRG" },
        { "date_from", "05/10/2023" },
        { "date_to ", "07/10/2023" }  ,
        { "return_from", "08/10/2023"},
        { "return_to", "10/10/2023" },
        //{ "nights_in_dst_from", "2" },
        //{ "nights_in_dst_to", "3" },
        { "max_Fly_Duration", "20" },
        { "ret_From_Diff_City", "true"},
        { "ret_to_Diff_City"," true"},
        { "one_For_City", "0" },
        { "one_per_date","0"},
        { "adults", "2" },
        { "children", "2" },
        { "selected_Cabins", "C" },
        { "mix_With_Cabins", "M" },
        { "adult_hold_bag", "1,0" },
        { "adult_hand_bag", "1,1" },
        { "child_hold_bag", "2,1" },
        { "child_hand_bag", "1,0" },
        { "only_Working_Days", "false" },
        { "onlyWeekEnd", "false" },
        { "partner_Market", "us" },
        { "max_Stopovers", "2" },
        { "max_sector_stopovers", "2" },
        { "vehicle_Type", "aircraft"},
        { "limit", "500"},
        }
    );
    return flightResult;``your text``
}`
and this is my BaseURL which is located in Appsettings.json 

"KiwiServiceConfig": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://api.tequila.kiwi.com/v2",
  "Kiwi_Key": "l9F6FUSfV9To1MMd1wFyeZ9zxnMC9l5A"
}
```

from my service my `endpoint="/search"` is not appending in my baseurl can some one please help me
Thanks

I had tried many things like placing search api keyword with my baseurl and is not working

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To format code blocks use four backticks on their own row (`\`\`\`\`) to start the code block and end it with the same. Its the same as in Github flavored markdown. You can also indent by four spaces or select the code block and press ctrl-k (cmd-k).

Comment: I am not sure whether it s appropriate to publicly post a key.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Is the problem that the API is returning an unexpected response (as the title suggests)?  Or is the problem that you're sending an incorrect request (as the description suggests)?  Also, what is `_httpService`?

Comment: it is the request that I am sending to get the response from the kiwi

Comment: any  help from you guy's for my probelem